# MSChart Nearest data point

Tags: vb.net, charts, mschart

I use Mschart to produce charts. What I am trying to get is *the nearest data point* by where I click on the chart. The problem is that I can't find any connection between the HitTest values and the data point x/y values.

Say, I clicked on the following point:

```
Dim result As HitTestResult = Chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
```

I have now values of X and Y where I clicked. 
How to associate it with the data point values?

What I want to achieve is to double-click on the chart which would find the nearest data point (x,y as integer) and knowing these values I would be able to recalculate other values based upon where the user needs it and double-clicks.

Any hints?
P.

EDIT:

So far it brought me here:

```
Dim selectedDataPoint As DataPoint = Nothing
    Dim hitResult As HitTestResult = Chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

    If hitResult.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
        selectedDataPoint = CType(hitResult.Object, DataPoint)
        MsgBox(selectedDataPoint.Name)
        MsgBox(selectedDataPoint.XValue.ToString)
        MsgBox(selectedDataPoint.YValues(0).ToString)
    End If
```

unfortunately the XValue gives me "0" as output where in fact I have string values composed with "weeknumber/yearnumber". Any idea why it is like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found an answer for my question. Please see the code below everyone who's interested:

```
If hitResult.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
            selectedDataPoint = CType(hitResult.Object, DataPoint)
            lblY.Text = selectedDataPoint.YValues(0).ToString
            lblX.Text = selectedDataPoint.AxisLabel.ToString
End if
```